My flutter app uses too much data from memory
Some users' app is killed due to data consumption issue of my flutter app.
And when i see my app's memory usage, it's 24.24GB in total.
It's too high.
So I check my memory leak from Android studio.
Basically, without any Leaks,

My app uses 2GB.

I think it's too high..
If it's not due to memory leak, just it basically takes too much memory, I can't figure out how to solve this problem.
Please help me..

It depends.  Some Android apps have lots and lots of Activities.  If you keep loading new ones and never unload the old ones then you will use more memory - but if you need all of them to be loaded all the time then there it will still be a problem.  I guess what I am saying is, we need some info about how your app is structured before we can suggest anything.

i encountered the same problem a while ago and i can share my analysis as per my Project Structure.
Using Flutter Isolate : While using flutter Isolate object i created ReceivePort and after the completion of my isolate task at the end of the function I forgot to close the same port by port.close() in resulting with the huge date object of that isolate post is getting created again and again and was not getting destroyed even when that statefull widget was destroyed with dispose() in it.
With the help of Flutter Inspector you can find at what place inside your app it is getting increase.
